# After upgrading ubuntu suddenly my laptop lost power and after that after logging in my pc stop proceeding to desktop what to do

Tags: upgrade

I cant enter my terminal how im gonna fix it when its not proceeding to my desktop is there is a way to recover it

Comment: This is why in the update manager, there is a legend that says you should have your equip conected to a power source for safety before updating/upgrading.

Comment: So what em i gonna do now